# Change PHP variable on button click

Tags: php

I'm making a like button - I can't use a SQL database because my data isn't stored in a database, so I'm thinking I can edit a PHP file when someone clicks on it. I want to do it without reloading the page, so here's what I'm thinking:

```
$likeFile = fopen("likes.php", [I'm not sure whether or not to put here])
fwrite($likeFile, + 1)
fclose($likeFile)
```

Only problem, I don't know how to add 1 to the variable, or select the variable at all.
[Image of the clap button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DIsC.png)
[Image of the clap variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JVM.png) (each one represents a page)
[Image of the clap html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpZRH.png) (like.php contains HTML for the clap, likes.php contains the variables)

Comment: When I saw the variables, boiling water spilled over my head. You should definitely use a database for this job. Open a new question and explain the database problem you are having.

Comment: What exactly is not working yet? Why not read the current content before writing it?

Comment: You should use JQuery+Ajax if you don't want to reload the page. And I also suggest you to use databse.

Comment: @sercanarga a couple things, first, my data isn't stored in a database in the first place. Most tutorials are telling me to add a "posts" SQL table, but I don't have any. Second of all, it's not logging in.

Comment: Only way to update a PHP variable without reloading the page is to use AJAX and keep the variable in session. But that value is lost when the session ends unless stored into a cookie or written into a file.  Without knowing more about your site design its hard to give other advice. But if this "like" button is intended to do what I think, you really should consider setting up a database.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, write it into the file.

Comment: Open the file and read the contents into some sort of structure (depends what data you have in the file) using FileReader. Update the value you want then write the contents back out to the file, overwriting the existing one. Ideally, you'd write to a temp file first and once complete, rename it to overwrite the original.